# How to validate if a string field is all uppercase without custom validators

Tags: python, pydantic

In pydantic, is there a way to validate if all letters in a string field are uppercase without a custom validator?

With the following I can turn input string into an all-uppercase string. But what I want is to validate the input so that no string with lower letters is allowed.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr
    
class FooSchema(BaseModel):
    foo: constr(to_upper=True)
```

and

```
foo_obj = FooSchema.parse_raw({foo:"abc"})
print(foo_obj.foo) # result: "ABC"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why "without custom validator"? That's what they are for...to validate custom conditions...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point but to check if a string is all uppercase then *mystring == mystring.upper()* is all you need

Comment: @Pingu I think you are right, but you need to put this line somewhere (in order to later raise an error or do any other logic). I think a custom validator for a field is a good place for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex`(`^[^a-z]*$`) parameter to validate the string if they all are in uppercase.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr
    
class FooSchema(BaseModel):
    foo: constr(regex=r"^[^a-z]*$")

foo_obj = FooSchema.parse_raw('{"foo":"ABc"}')
# ERROR
# 1 validation error for FooSchema
# foo
# string does not match regex "^[^a-z]*$" (type=value_error.str.regex; pattern=^[^a-z]*$)
```